# Создание отчета комиссионера о продажах

Tags: 1с, база-данных

Хы, добрался я и до этого.

Сижу, ковыряю документ "Отчет комиссионера". А точнее форму, пытаюсь понять, как происходит запись. Что хочу: заменить данные, передаваемые из формы на свои, чтобы потом заюзать сохранение отчета в другом месте.

Запросы понял как делать:

```
ИскомыйПартнер = Справочники.Партнеры.НайтиПоКоду("ЦБ-00000010");
Организация = Справочники.Организации.НайтиПоРеквизиту("ИНН", "...");
//...
```

Вопрос собственно такой сейчас: каким образом можно создать этот документ? Что-то ковыряние в исходниках формы результатов не принесли :(

Comment: Можно так:

    ИскомыйКонтрагент = Справочники.Контрагенты.НайтиПоКоду("ЦБ-00000010");
    Если не ИскомыйКонтрагент.Пустая() Тогда
      ...

Запросы вроде верный. Воспользуйтесь конструктором запросов. На тексте запроса правой кнопкой "Конструктор запроса". Если все-таки выдает ошибку, попробуйте новый запрос написать с помощью конструктора...

Comment: А не подойдёт `Справочник.Контрагенты.Код`?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov сейчас попробовал создать через конструктор запрос с выводом - в консоли вываливается куча ошибок. *_*

Comment: Организация = Справочники.Организации.НайтиПоРеквизиту("ИНН", "...");    

Данный стиль очень плох по той причине, что если вы найдете по реквизиту объект, то получите его целиком (а в объекте может быть множество реквизитов, включая картинки), вместо того чтобы получить только его ссылку, также, предположим, вы ищете по неуникальному реквизиту, то по идее пользователь может завести несколько объектов с этим реквизитом? Какой из них вы получите?

Comment: @Егор Соколов хз, в ДокументОбъект.ОтчетКомиссионера передается объект. ИНН по идее уникальное значение.

Comment: Если вы будете объект записывать/проводить то, вам нужно будет получать объект. В случаях, где нужно заполнять реквизиты формы / выводить печатные формы достаточно будет использовать ссылку. В принципе у вас вопрос стоит как создать документ. Тогда вам действительно нужно получить объект, если таковой документ уже имеется, или же создать новый, если нет 

> НовыйДокумент = Документы.ВашДокумент.СоздатьДокумент();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Егор Соколов](/users/1428/%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

> Данный стиль очень плох по той причине, что если вы найдете по реквизиту объект, то получите его целиком (а в объекте может быть множество реквизитов, включая картинки)

Неверно. Возвратится только ссылка на объект. Если не обращаться к другим реквизитам, то загрузка всего объекта не произойдет. Другое дело, что порой можно сделать один запрос на все необходимые данные при записи/проведении/печати и т.д., это верно.

[@lampa](/users/5030/lampa) В 1С есть понятие Объект и есть понятие Ссылка. Первый из них представляет собой объект элемента метаданных, у которого можно менять реквизиты, а также его можно записывать и удалять, содержит в себе все значения всех реквизитов. Ссылка - более легкий способ обращения к данным элемента, в частности при многократном обращении к одним и тем же реквизитам происходит кэширование значений реквизитов.

Так вот, когда открывается форма документа, то у нее есть основной реквизит Объект (для 8.2), который представляет собой именно тот самый объект со всеми свойствам и методами записи и удаления. Таким образом, вам не нужно вручную создавать этот объект, он уже создан. Создан он в памяти пока не будет вызван метод Записать() (явно или неявно - по кнопке ОК).

Если же создание происходит в коде, то код примерно таков:

```
Док = Документы.ОтчетКомиссионера.СоздатьДокумент();
Док.Организация = Справочники.Организации.НайтиПоЗначениюРеквизита("ИНН","...");
...
Док.Записать();//РежимЗаписи по умолчанию Запись, если нужно то надо указать другой режим
```

Comment: Док.Организация = Справочники.Организации.НайтиПоЗначениюРеквизита("ИНН","...");

На счет этого понятно, допер всё-таки. Даже научился доставать партнера. Но блин, пол дня потратил на то, чтобы понять, как выбрать контрагента партнера и соглашение партнера. Но так и не додумался. Искал долго :(

Comment: Насколько я понимаю у вас типовая конфигурация. Так вот чтоб создать документ и правильно заполнить все его реквизиты (договора, вид операции и т.д.) можно подсмотреть в обработчиках в форме ПриОткрытии ПриСозданииНаСервере, а также обработчики интерактивного изменения данных - ПриИзменении (в основном, но могут быть и другие важны) для реквизитов. Часть из них может подставляться автоматом или рассчитываться, для этого есть соответствующие универсальные процедуры в общих модулях, в модуле формы просто происходит их вызов. Таким образом, часто бывает необходимо заполнить лишь важные реквизиты

Comment: @Yura Ivanov это да, данные в форму вставляются отлично. Но у меня суть в том, что я хочу сделать добавление документа автоматически, раз в день например. Или вы про это и говорите?

Comment: ДАДАДА, ПартнерыИКонтрагенты.ПолучитьКонтрагентаПартнераПоУмолчанию(Партнер);